# Which datastructure to use for finding an element

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, find

I have several items saved in a list. I would like to add items that have already been processed to a datastructure (this makes sense in my case even though you might wonder why). When processing the next item from the list I first want to make sure if it has been processed before so lets say something like this:

```
if(element_is_in_datastructure(current_element)) {
   do this
}
else
{
   do that
   add_element_to_datastructure(current_element)
}
```

My question is, what is the ideal datastructure where checking if the element is in it won't take too long. At the moment I don't have too many elements (max 30) which will be added to the datastructure, but this number might increase and I don't want to lose performance.

Comment: You probably want to use `std::set` or `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `map` e.g `std::unordered_map` to store your elements as `keys`. 
Then just check their presence e.g

```
if(!yourMap.count(element))
{
   // your element is not in the structure
}
```

This finding takes logarithmic time in the map's size to finish.

Comment: It is not constant time. It is logarithmic.

Comment: Thanks, I edit it ^^

Comment: If all you need is a set of elements, then perhaps `std::set` is a better option, much like the map it's stored in a tree, but only stores the 1 element and not a pair, which you don't need.

Comment: May be fix it again? Logarithmic for map, constant for unordered_map and unordered_set?

Comment: It is constant for best-case and linear for worst-case scenarios, so logarithmic time seems conclusive for it. =]]